# argparse and mutually exclusive groups, each with their own required setting

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, mutual-exclusion

I have a program that needs to have an option to either test a list of server ids *OR* issue a command against the server.  This means, if I issue `--test`, then nothing else is required.  It runs the whole gamut of tests against each server and prints the results.

However, if I do NOT specify `--test`, then it should require a few options such as `--id` and `--command`.

However, I'm not sure that `argparse` can handle required options within mutually exclusive groups.  Code (modified for simplicity) is as follows.  I've modified the options so if you specify `-a`, then you SHOULD be good to go and no other options be necessary.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

test_or_not = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
test_or_not.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
or_not = test_or_not.add_argument_group()
target = or_not.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
target.add_argument('-b',action="store_true")
target.add_argument('-c',action="store_true")
target.add_argument('-d',action="store_true")
target.add_argument('-e',action="store_true")
group = or_not.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-f',action="store_true")
group.add_argument('-g',action="store_true")
or_not.add_argument('-i',action="store_true")
or_not.add_argument('-j',action="store_true")
or_not.add_argument('-k',action="store_true")
or_not.add_argument('-l',action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

The resulting error is produced because `argparse` is still requiring individual options even though they're in a mutually exclusive group.  Is there a way that `argparse` can accommodate this set of options or do I need to add a bit of programming outside of `argparse`?

```
$ python3 ~/tmp/groups.py -a
usage: groups.py [-h] -a (-b | -c | -d | -e) (-f | -g) [-i] [-j] [-k] [-l]
groups.py: error: one of the arguments -b -c -d -e is required
```

Edit:  I could add a new option that entirely works OUTSIDE of `argparse` as below, but I'd like to keep it structured within `argparse` if at all possible.

```
import argparse
import sys

if '--test' in sys.argv:
    go_do_testing()
    sys.exit(0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
<snip>
```

Comment: Couldn't you make the `test` option a `subparser` and tie the `subparser` to the function that checks those servers?

Comment: I did not know this was a thing.  I swear I've read through and referenced the argparse docs a hundred times over, but Hand to God, I've never noticed that.  I do feel kinda dumb...

Comment: haha. If it comes close to helping with what you're trying to do and that you could not find a duplicate of this on here, then please feel free to write an answer to share your findings.

Comment: I was just going to say the same to you.  Please make this an answer so I can properly accept it.

Comment: If [the solution here](https://gist.github.com/AbdouSeck/cb50fbbb2c99b4d9cd3e62305b3c6716) looks good, it can be posted here as well.

Comment: Argument_group and mutually_exclusive_groups are not designed to be nested.  A mutually_exclusive_group can be put in an argument_group for the purpose of help line labeling, but that's it.  Argument_group is a help line grouping mechanism.  Mutually_exclusive_group is a testing mechanism (and can show up in the usage line).  Other than `subparsers` there isn't a mechanism in `argparse` for 'mutually-inclusive' testing or other more complex logical combinations.  You have to do that kind of testing yourself, after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj, I agree with you and that's exactly what I found with Abdou's answer.  Now, if only I could get him to post it as a real answer so I could accept it....  ;)

Comment: @UtahJarhead, apologies about the delay. Please see posted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the way to go, if you wish to have mutually exclusive `test` and `run` logics, would be to use subparsers. The following is an illustration of the idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Script to test or run commands on given servers.
./the_script.py test  # To test all servers
./the_script.py run --id 127.0.0.1 --command "echo hello world"
"""
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawDescriptionHelpFormatter as RDHF


def test_servers(servers):
    """
    Given a list of servers, let's test them!
    """
    for server in servers:
        print('Just tested server {s}'.format(s=server))

def do_actual_work(server_id, command):
    """
    Given a server ID and a command, let's run the command on that server!
    """
    print('Connected to server {s}'.format(s=server_id))
    print('Ran command {c} successfully'.format(c=command))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=RDHF)
    subs = parser.add_subparsers()
    subs.required = True
    subs.dest = 'run or test'
    test_parser = subs.add_parser('test', help='Test all servers')
    test_parser.set_defaults(func=test_servers)
    run_parser = subs.add_parser('run', help='Run a command on the given server')
    run_parser.add_argument('-i', '--id',
                            help='The ID of the server to connect to and run commands',
                            required=True)
    run_parser.add_argument('-c', '--command',
                            help='The command to run',
                            required=True)
    run_parser.set_defaults(func=do_actual_work)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if args.func.__name__ == 'test_servers':
        all_servers = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2']
        test_servers(all_servers)
    else:
        do_actual_work(args.id, args.command)
```

The script sets up both mutually exclusive and required subparsers `test` and `run`. For the `test` subparser, nothing else is required. However, for the `run` subparser, both `--id` and `--command` would be required. Each of these subparsers is associated with its designated target function. For simplicity I had the `test_parser` tied to `test_servers`; while `run_parser` is associated with `do_actual_work`.

Further, you should be able to call the script as follows to run all tests:

```
./the_script.py test
```

To run a specific command on a specific server, you call the script as follows:

```
./the_script.py run --id 127 --command "echo hello world"
```

I hope this proves useful.