# Python(argparse): required arguments in one branch of mutually exlusive group

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have the following code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='do stuff')

TOP = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
#
TOP.add_argument('--interactive', action="store_true")
noninteractive = TOP.add_argument_group()
##
noninteractive.add_argument('--required1', required=True, type=float)
noninteractive.add_argument('--required2', required=True, type=float)
##
noninteractive_excl = noninteractive.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
noninteractive_excl.add_argument('--mutuallyexcl1', default=None, type=float)
noninteractive_excl.add_argument('--mutuallyexcl2', default=None, type=float)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

My program should work like this:

You can either call it with the option `--interactive` (which then will ask the user to enter the data step by step) or a group of arguments containing all necessary options for running the program. The group and `--interactive` shall be mutually exclusive.

The group then has two options which are required and two options that are mutually exclusive again.

My expectation was, that, when called with `--interactive`, the program would not ask for any other arguments since they are in a group which is part of the first mutually exclusive group.
Instead, when I call the program with

```
python dostuff.py --interactive
```

I get the following message:

```
dostuff.py: error: the following arguments are required: --required1, --required2
```

What did I do wrong and how can I fix this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it gets thrown off because your mutually exclusive group contains an argument and another group. The recommendation is to use sub-parsers. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52865331/843953

Comment: Subparsers are something that I looked into but if I understood them correctly, that would mean that I had call the function with `dostuff.py interactive --somearg`. Instead, I would like to be able to simply use `dostuff.py --interactive `.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading more into the groups than is supported by the docs or the code.  `argument_group` is just a "help" display tool.  `mutually_exclusive_group` is a simple `xor`, without any nesting.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='do stuff')

TOP = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
#
TOP.add_argument('--interactive', action="store_true")
```

Everything added to `noninteractive` is also part of the `TOP` group.  None of them can be required.

```
noninteractive = TOP.add_argument_group()
##
noninteractive.add_argument('--required1', required=True, type=float)
noninteractive.add_argument('--required2', required=True, type=float)
##
```

These two arguments are `required`.  The fact that they are in the argument_group makes no difference.  That's not a logical  "any" group.

That includes this group - the `xor` is flattened.

```
noninteractive_excl = noninteractive.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
noninteractive_excl.add_argument('--mutuallyexcl1', default=None, type=float)
noninteractive_excl.add_argument('--mutuallyexcl2', default=None, type=float)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

`mutually_exclusive_group` does not cut parsing short.  It's not a branching mechanism. It is just a test for occurance.  If you provide `--iteractive`, it will raise an error if you provide any of the other arguments in the group.  Your example didn't cause that error, but it still tests for `required` arguments. In other words, these are just tests; they don't alter parsing order.

The `subparsers` mechanism does create alternative parsing paths.  Only one of the subparsers is used, parsing the remaining arguments according to its own setup.